# WEBDEV : How to add some HTML into a Cell container?

Tags: html, web, chart.js

I am trying to add some charts into my WEBDEV page. For this, I created an Intern Component (it is usefull for reuse it later in other projects), and this intern component contains a cell container. I want my chart to be into this cell container.

But the problem is here : ChartJs need a `<canvas></canvas>` to show the chart.
I can't find the way to put in this element into the cell, only before or after, but this put the chart before or after the cell container...

This is what I used for the moment. This code is in the global declarations (server code) of the control template of my intern component :

```
gsEntete is string = [
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
]

gsCanvas is string = [
    <canvas id="myChart" style="width:100%;valign:center"></canvas>
]

MyPage.HTMLHeader += gsEntete
CELL_Container.HTMLBefore += gsCanvas
```